# Can a low-wattage adapter fully recharge the battery of a turned off MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

MacBooks come with power adapters that provide a certain wattage (for example 87 W) required to keep the computer running and charge the battery. If used with a lower-wattage power adapter (for example 61 W), there might not be enough power to keep the computer running. However, could such a lower-wattage power adapter be used to fully recharge the battery if the computer is kept turned off?

Could even a low-wattage iPhone charger be used for this, although it would probably take a long time?

Update: The question concerns newer MacBooks with USB-C chargers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are referencing the MacBooks and MacBook Pros with USB-C ports (2016 and up), the short answer is yes, a low power adapter could charge the MacBook which requires a higher power adapter to function.

(and yes, it will take a very, very long time)

As for Macs with the MagSafe adapter, since the DC-In board (or MagSafe power board) "checks" the power coming it, if it's not of the right voltage/wattage, it won't charge.

Comment: Yes, the question concerns MacBooks with USB-C ports. The question has been updated to mention this.

Comment: Were newer MacBooks intentionally changed to allow charging using lower-wattage power adapters to make other USB-C chargers that might be lying around useful also for MacBooks (instead of just refusing to charge if the wattage isn't right like the older MacBooks)?

Comment: No.  It's the USB-C power delivery spec. in which power delivery is actually negotiated.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, it will charge from a lower-wattage adapter so long as the computer is not burning the energy faster than the charger is providing it.**

I personally have a 15" 2016 MBP. It came with an 87W adapter, which I usually leave at work. At home, I have an Anker USB-PD 60W adapter. Typically lack of wattage isn't noticeable, but on a few occasions, while running the MacBook Pro hard, I have noticed the battery is not charging, or even *draining*. In that case I need to calm things down or plug in the 87W adapter.*

Anything with a USB-PD charger should be able to charge the battery, even the 30W model, though in that case your MacBook Pro may need to be asleep to charge.

**Fun fact, you don't actually need to unplug the 60W adapter in this case, the computer will draw from the higher wattage adapter, and stop drawing from the lower.* [See this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259746/68014).

### Update in 2020

I've now charged on low-power chargers countless times. I've even recharged overnight with a 3A phone charger when I didn't have anything better. It takes hours but you'll have a full charge in the morning.

Theoretically, the 15" Macbook's 7.2Ah battery would charge in 4 hours assuming 60% efficiency, that the charger actually puts out a full 3 amps, and there is no usage during that time. At 2.4A, you'd be around 5 hours and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices like Thinkpad X1 Tablet and XPS 15 require at least 45W charger when turned on. Error message claims such charger may work during sleep or turned off states.