# Will two charging cables charge my laptop twice as quickly?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

Now that the MacBook has all of its ports the same, is it possible to plug in two power cables into the Mac?

If I do so, will it charge twice as quickly? In the event that the Mac is unable to allow that amount of current in at once, is there a mechanism to limit how much is allowed in, or else cut it off entirely?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to plug in two power cables into the Mac?

No.

The MacBook will [use the charger that provides the most amount of power](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298465/how-to-know-which-one-is-used-when-charging-a-macbook-pro-with-usb-c-from-multip).

> In the event that the Mac is unable to allow that amount of current in
>   at once, is there a mechanism to limit how much is allowed in, or else
>   cut it off entirely?

The [USB 3.1 power delivery specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/) calls for the negotiation of charge to be delivered.  If you plug more than one it, it will simply refuse the one providing the least amount of power.