# Turn off power output from a USB Type C Monitor

Tags: charging

I'm currently using my MacBook Pro with an external Benq Monitor (4K HDR) with a USB-Type C connection.

The problem is that it's also simultaneously charging my laptop over this same connection and the amount of power it can supply is much less that what my laptop needs.  So, it doesn't charge properly.

Now, what I would like to do is disable the power output from the monitor and have the laptop only take charging from the Apple power adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Just plug in a “larger” power adapter like the one your Mac came with.  It’s not that it will use both simultaneously, but instead it will select the charger that’s delivering the most current.

[What happens if you plug more than one charger in the new MacBook Pro (2016)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/259744/119271)